# I2C initialization as a master on K22F

Tags: c, arm, i2c, master-slave

I'm working with ARM FRDM-K22F Microprocessor and I want to see the waveform on oscilloscope while initializing I2C as a master. The problem is that after I generated the code I wrote a code in main.c to check the master bus to see if it's busy and if not I decided to transmit some data and show it on oscilloscope. But unfortunately it seems like the bus is always busy and it doesn't enter the if condition. Is there anyone who could help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: you might want to share your snippet and add the tag c

Comment: ARM does not manufacture silicon devices. They are an an IP-company. Could you please clarify the vendor of that device?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pull-ups on the I2C bus lines?
If not, the bus will always be busy.